# Повторение глагола-связки

Tags: синтаксис, грамматика, глаголы, однородные-члены, связка

**Если вы сами не будете активно действовать, а будете пускать всё на самотёк и (будете) оставлять своё продвижение на усмотрение другим — дальше старшего специалиста вы не продвинетесь.**

Подскажите, пожалуйста, правило, которое устанавливает, когда лучше повторять глагол-связку при однородных членах, а когда — опускать (как в случае с однородными членами с одинаковыми предлогами, частицами "бы" и т.д.).

Дополнение:

Как правило, когда однородный член заметно распространён зависимыми словами, то повторение глагола-связки, предлога, частицы "бы" и т.д. позволяет человеку не упустить то, что однородный член относится к этому глаголу-связке, предлогу, частице, не "потерять" связь с ними.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У меня в руках книга, которая называется **"Информационный стиль и редактура текста"** (учебное пособие для внутреннего пользования).

**Информационный стиль (ИС)** — это  не стиль в обычном понимании, его вы не найдете  в учебниках  русского языка. Это просто **принцип сильного текста любого жанра.**

**Главное понятие ИС — информативность, которая определяется как отношение переданной информации  к объему текста.** Отметим, что информативность зависит от стиля и художественный текст, к примеру,  имеет особую (образную) информативность. А вот к деловому стилю такой подход применяется непосредственно.

Поэтому нужно взять предложение, определить его информационное содержание и изложить с помощью простых синтаксических конструкций  с минимальным количеством слов, например так:

**Если не действовать активно, а  пускать всё на самотёк и  оставлять своё продвижение на усмотрение другим, то дальше старшего специалиста вы не продвинетесь.**

**Оценим, что получилось.** Информация передана в том же объеме, но при этом 23 слова вместо 27 слов, ни одного повтора (а это общее стилистическое требование) и  упрощенный синтаксис, удобный для чтения.

Comment: Полностью согласен. Касательно повторения задал вопрос в комментариях пользователю Alex_ander. Хотелось бы и ваше мнение увидеть насчёт такой функции.

Comment: Здесь нет общих правил,  а письменный текст по восприятию отличается от устного. Что касается вашего примера,  то там связки нет, а есть сложная форма будущего времени.  Без повтора глагол "быть" обойтись нельзя при наличии союза А, а для союза И повтор нежелателен. Автор не должен усложнять синтаксис без особых на это причин. С другой стороны, повтор может быть средством художественной выразительности. Поэтому есть только самые общие рекомендации,  а само решение зависит от конкретного текста.

Answer (score 1):

Руководствоваться в этом нужно не столько правилами, сколько чувством меры и особенностями ситуации. Иногда намеренные излишние повторения служат оратору для поддержания внимания толпы, а в обычном тексте они же могут восприниматься как назойливость или недостаточные речевые навыки. Если помните, в "Пигмалионе" профессор Хиггинс приписал мусорщику Дулиттлу "врождённый дар риторики" после того, как тот употребил несколько глаголов, каждый снабдив новым "я". В вашем примере (как и во многих неясных случаях) несложно избавиться от двух "будете" и одного "вы":

> Если сами вы вместо того, чтобы активно действовать, будете пускать
>   всё на самотёк и оставлять своё продвижение на усмотрение другим, то
>   дальше старшего специалиста не продвинетесь.

Comment: Просто, как правило, когда однородный член заметно распространён зависимыми словами, то повторение глагола-связки, предлога, частицы "бы" и т.д. позволяет человеку не упустить то, что однородный член относится к этому глаголу-связке, предлогу, частице. Разве нет?

Comment: "Заметность распространённости" влияет на выбор, но она субъективна. Этот пример мне не кажется настолько "развеситым", чтобы лишний раз освежать память читающего. Если же рассматривать его как заготовку устной речи, то соотв. добавления терпимы, поскольку на слух информация воспринимается хуже.

Answer (score 0):

Не могу сказать, есть ли такое правило. Общий подход — избегать повторений, не вносящих ничего нового. Очевидно, что взятое в скобки - лишнее.

Comment: Дополнил вопрос. Хотелось бы узнать ваше мнение насчёт такой функции.

Comment: Присоединяюсь к сказанному @Alex_ander